# java garbage collection and temporary objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm a c++ developer by trade, but I've been doing a bit Java lately. This project I'm working in was done by a developer long since gone and I keep finding things where he is working around the Garbage collection by doing weird things.

Case and point he implemented his own string class to avoid slow down by GC

This section of the app takes a large binary file format and exports it to csv. This means building up a string for each line in the file (millions). In order to avoid those temporary string objects he made a string class that just has a large array of bytes he reuses.

```
/**
 HACK
     A Quick and Dirty string builder implementation optimized for GC.
     Using String.format causes the application grind to a halt when
     more than a couple of string operations are performed due to the number of
     temporary objects allocated while formatting strings for drawing or logging.    
*/
```

Does this actually help? is this really needed? Is this better than just declaring a String object outside the loop and setting it inside the loop?

The app also has a hash map containing doubles for the values. The keys in the map are fairly static but the values change often. Afraid of GC on doubles he made a myDouble class to use as the value for the hashmap

```
/**
 *  This is a Mutable Double Wrapper class created to avoid GC issues
 *
 */
public class MyDouble implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = C.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;
    public double d;

    public MyDouble(double d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

This is crazy and completely unnecessary... right?

Comment: Why don't you test it with the alternative and see if it makes a difference? Depending on when it's been written, it's likely that the JVM has improved a lot since then and the code is no longer necessary, but it's still entirely possible to significantly outperform the standard memory allocator, simply because it has to be standard and, with your own code, you can write it specifically for your scenario.

Comment: Did that wise mean leave behind benchmarks? If not, come up with some yourself, and dock the credibility score by a few points. Now you can quantify the effect of changes and can start simplifying the code where it does not unduly affect performance.

Comment: To answer your first questions: Yes, it *could* help, however it seems like he has reinvented the wheel here.  Now-a-days we use the `StringBuilder` class, which basically does the same thing with a char buffer and allows mutatable strings.  To answer your second question: No, creating the string reference outside the loop and setting it inside the loop will still create a whole bunch of strings.  String literals are sort of a "special case" in java.  If your application is creating lots of unique little strings, or appending a lot (which I suspect is the case), GC could be very busy.

Comment: How old is this code? Why not to use MutableDouble fro Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableDouble.html

Comment: That class was added to source code 2012-10-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that string concatenation can be a bottleneck in Java because `String`s are immutable.  This means each concatenation creates a new `String`, unless a matching `String` was previously created and is therefore in the string-pool (see [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)).  Either way, it can certainly lead to problems.

However your predecessor is not the first person to have encountered this and the standard way to deal with the need to concatenate many `String`s in Java is to use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

When a `double` (or any primative for that matter) is used as a local variable, it's kept on the stack and the memory it occupies released along with the stack frame (non sure if they're subject to GC or taken care of by the JVM as it runs).  If however the `double` is the field on an object, it's stored on the heap and will be collected when the object containing it is collected.

Without seeing how the `double` values are being used, it hard to say for sure, but it's more than likely the use of the `Map` has increased the GC load.

In summary, yes, imho this is certainly, as you say 'crazy and completely unnecessary'.  These sorts of premature optimizations only serve to complicate the code base making it more prone to bugs and making future maintenance more difficult.  The golden rule should practically always be, build the simplest thing that works, profile it and then optimize.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of StringBuilder